# Make it so the information the user provided in input field can be modified and redisplayed with Django

Tags: python, html, django, forms, view

I am currently trying to make a password manager with Django. The code for it can be found [here](https://github.com/ShaneWD/PasswordManagerWebsite), and the version of the code I'm referencing is when commit id "39dd9110a8aa098399af0511a963e447a0d45afb" was pushed to GitHub. **All code referenced will be in the django app titled "main".**

The home page looks like this: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJpxb.png)

This is what the page in question looks like: [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8fk8.png)
(In the project, this page is displayed after clicking the text "GitHub")

In the input area, the user provides their master password, and then clicks the submit button. I would like to retrieve that password and alter it(I will use it to decrypt their other passwords, but I do not need help decrypting, I need help altering it). And after altering it, I would like to display the altered text on the page.

In the file named "detailed_view.html", the code containing the input field is wrapped in form tags.

Code:

```
<form method = "POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h1 style="display:inline; color: #4CAF50">Password</h1>
    <input type="password" name="Password" style="display:inline;">
    <input style="position: absolute;left: 50%;display:block;" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

After the user clicks "submit", the information is brought to the view() function in views.py (line 64):

```
@login_required
def view(request, pk):
    if request.method =="POST":
        return HttpResponse(request)

    location = Location.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {
        'location': location
    }

    return render(request, "main/detail_view.html", context)
```

After which, the user is directed to a page where it displays the CSRF Middleware Token with the password they inputted.

Ex: if the user inputted the text "password123", it will display something like this: "csrfmiddlewaretoken=nfQ3bn6d2Cxa7sFJXyIInaHaFkq6T5BkaXn2RCvrSRNVq4HNmakkh6OeGWELkKf&Password=password123".
I would like to retrieve the last part ("password123") to use it to decrypt.

Extra: Is there a way to retieve it without being prone to SQL injections?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to my own problem:

I made the form method POST and I added a name in the input box. I named it "testing123":

```
<form method = "POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h1 style="display:inline; color: #4CAF50">Password</h1>
    <input type="password" name = "testing123" name="Password" style="display:inline;">
    <input style="position: absolute;left: 50%;display:block;" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Thus, when the user clicks submit, it is seen as a POST request. The view can be configured to take in the POST request (if request.method =="POST"):

```
def view(request, pk):
    if request.method =="POST":
        epic = request.POST.get("testing123")
        return HttpResponse(epic)

    else:
        location = Location.objects.get(id=pk)
    
    context = {
        'location': location
    }

    return render(request, "main/detail_view.html", context)
```

As seen above, I used **request.POST.get("testing123")** to get the information the user inputted in the input box (recall that the input box was called "testing123" ). I stored that information into a variable, named "epic", and returned that information as an Http Response. Thus, since the information can be captured in a variable and in string form, I can alter it all I want and it can be used to decrypt the user's passwords.